# How can I get the exact screen size of the device through code?

Tags: android

I used the below code to find out the screen size but I am not getting correct values.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    int height=display.getHeight();
```

It returns 320 x 480 for galaxy tab.. which is not correct.

How do I find the correct screen size of the galaxy tab which is 600 x 1024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like Android thinks that your application is a "legacy" app (i.e. one designed for old versions of Android). From [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> For instance, suppose a given device is using a WVGA medium density screen, classified as a "large" screen, but the application states that it does not support large screens; in this case, the system will again "lie" to the application when it queries for screen dimensions, and report 320x480.

Comment: So, was this your problem? It would be courteous to let us know whether the answers we're giving you are of any help. I noticed that you've not accepted *any* of the answers to *any* of the questions you've asked.

Answer (score 3):

I always use this one, and never encountered an error:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context){
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getWidth();
}
public static int getScreenHeight(Context context){
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your program, width's unit is px, your said 600 is possible dp value，you can use the follow code to verify:

```
final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

prite scale to see, if scale = 320/600 = 0.5333333, that is to say 600 is dp value.